# Converting a double to a time that makes sense

Tags: c#, datetime

Basically I  am setting a limit of hours a user can use. Now every time a button is press, whatever time that person accrued gets taken away from  this total value.

However because a limit would be represented as say 156 hours, and  the datetime representation of 5 minutes would be 00.05 the result would be 155.95, rather than 155.55 .

I work this out like so

```
 string date2 = TotalMonthlyHours.ToString("HH.mm");
                    double date = double.Parse(date2);                  
                    RunningTotal = date + RunningTotal;
                    Total = limit - RunningTotal;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Taking five minutes away from a double containing the value 156 should neither result in 155.95 nor in 155.55. It should result in `155.9166666`, because 5 minutes is `5 / 60` = `0.083333333` of one hour. Taking thirty minutes away should result in `155.50`, because 30 minutes are 0.5 of one hour.

Comment: Why not try and use a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) instead of a double?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to represent 5 minutes as 0.05. The way to do that is to first of all obtain the minutes as an integer. And then simply convert to double.

```
double floatmins = minutes/100.0;
```

And you convert in the other direction like this:

```
int minutes = (int) (floatmins*100.0);
```

However, I urge you not to go any further with this. You cannot expect to perform arithmetic on a quantity like that. What is the result of 2.20-1.50? You and I know it's 30 minutes, but the computer says 0.70 which is no use at all.

Store the hours using a true fractional representation. So 5 minutes is `5/60.0`. Or store the total minutes in an integer. Or total seconds in an integer. Or a `TimeSpan`.

The key is that you can write your own helper routines to convert from a sane storage format to a value that is human readable. But you must store the raw data in a representation that will admit arithmetic operations.

Comment: I suppose i'm struggling thinking how I can convert  156 to hours and minutes, and convert my double to hours and minutes, because Datetime seems to just revert back to 00.00 and timespans require datetimes to operate

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromHours(156)`. What makes you think you have to use date times with `TimeSpan`

Comment: Got it working, I'll accept your answer since what you told me  about my logic being flawed steered me towards the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked it out by doing something like this

```
                   string[] times = date.ToString().Split('.');

                    if (date != 0.0)
                    {
                        string minutesString = times[1];
                        string hoursString = times[0];
                        double minutes = Convert.ToDouble(minutesString);
                        double hours = Convert.ToDouble(hoursString);

                        // end of splitting
                        TimeSpan Limit = TimeSpan.FromHours(limit);

                        TimeSpan Hours = TimeSpan.FromHours((int)hours);
                        TimeSpan Minutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((int)minutes);

                        TimeSpan SubTotal = Hours + Minutes;


                        Time = Limit - SubTotal;
                    }
```

Edit: Glad you came up with the same as me,Just read your reply David, let's hope it works

Answer (score 0):

I would convert it to minutes first than add as minutes to the date

```
var min = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDecimal(textbox.Text) * 60);
DateTimePickerEnd.DbSelectedDate = e.NewDate.Value.AddMinutes(min);
```